# How far have we developed eco-friendly tyres alternatives?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, wheels, highway-engineering, roadway

Considering how bad rubber tires is for environment ([Microplastic on tyre - NatGeo](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/environment/2019/09/tires-unseen-plastic-polluter/#:%7E:text=Today%20tires%20consist%20of%20about,of%20metal%20and%20other%20compounds)),

> Today tires consist of about 19 percent natural rubber and 24 percent synthetic rubber, which is a plastic polymer. The rest is made up of metal and other compounds. Producing tires still has monumental environmental impacts, ranging from continued deforestation to the climate-harming fossil fuels used to make synthetic rubbers to the assembly process. Modern car tires require about 7 gallons of oil to make, while truck tires take 22 gallons
>
> A 2013 report by Tire Steward Manitoba, in Canada, found that
> passenger light truck tires lost nearly 2.5 pounds of rubber during
> their service life (average of 6.33 years). The Kohl study found that
> Americans produce the most tire wear per capita and estimates that,
> overall, tires in the U.S. alone produce about 1.8 million tons of
> microplastics each year.
>
> Exactly how much of that waste ends up in waterways depends on many
> factors, says Sousa, ranging from where the road is located to the
> weather; rain, for example, can cause more particles to flow into the
> environment. Research into the topic is relatively new, he notes, so
> estimates will improve as more work is done. But with millions of
> vehicles traveling the streets every day, he says, “you start to have
> a grim idea about the amount of tire (particles) released.”

How far have we developed eco-friendly tyres alternatives?

Would metal mesh like what NASA have on their rover ([nitinol tyre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2iHopdlFBg)) would be answer to this?

[image]

[image]

Considering it's airless, strong, and lightweight characteristic, while still fully recycleable in a closed loop

The only downside is the cost. But might could be replaced with steel-variant mesh

Not sure about comfortability & high speed noise & vibration though

What do you think?

Comment: Delete then re-post? Not good.

Comment: An award-winning project to collect and recycle the worn  materials: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/science-environment-54980602

Comment: @SolarMike Previous question wasn't clearly describe relevant topics on 
engineering, so i intend to narrow it down considering a change in whole topic direction before going too far (was just 6 views with no answer)

Comment: Walking would be very ecofriendly.